# wx python get icon from blob

Tags: sqlite, wxpython

Can anyone please point me to a resource that will help me get an icon from blob in wx.python

I can do it from a  file

```
ico = wx.Icon('bfgIcon.ico', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO)
self.SetIcon(ico)
```

but I cannot seem to find the correct way of doing it from an sql blob. I've tried

```
row=uc.Users().GeneralImageRow('bfgLogo')
stream=wx.InputStream(StringIO(row[1])) 
image=stream.GetIcon()
self.SetIcon(image)
```

but I've clearly got the object architecture wrong

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

OK. Got it [here](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/21601/wx.IconBundle)

```
row=uc.Users().GeneralImageRow('bfgLogo')
stream=wx.InputStream(StringIO(row[1])) 
icon=wx.IconFromBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(wx.ImageFromStream(stream,wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)))
self.SetIcon(icon)
```

Comment: Using wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY will try to autodetect the format, rather than wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG which is specific.